# hide .img javascript onload

Tags: javascript

Why this code does not work correct? I searching .img attribute but style is not changing and always picture is visible.

HTML

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function displayDate()
    {
            $('img[alt=image2]').css("display","none");
            $('img[alt=image3]').css("display","none");
            $('img[alt=image4]').css("display","none");

            $('img[alt=image2]').css("visibility","visible");
            $('img[alt=image3]').css("visibility","visible");
            $('img[alt=image4]').css("visibility","visible");
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<body OnLoad="displayDate()">
<img src="im.jpg" alt="image2"/>
<img src="im.jpg" alt="image3"/>
<img src="im.jpg" alt="image4"/>
</body>
```

you can see error in chrome

[image]

Comment: At which point does it fail? Does it find each element?

Comment: you wanna make invisible each img or just three, as above in the question?

Comment: yes I would like te invisible each img but this code not working correct. I don`t know why? and pictures are visible

Comment: What exactly is not working correctly? Any errors in the error console? Does the function fire at all? Does a `console.log( $('img[alt=image2]'))` show that jQuery is actually finding the element?

Comment: You are sure, that you implemented jQuery? Because your code contains jQuery syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that you don't have the jQuery library included while you are using jQuery syntax. So try to include the jQuery library by adding this to the `<head>` of your page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The jQuery way to execute something on load is like this:

```
$(function() {
   // this code will execute on load
});
```

The jQuery way to hide an element is like this:

```
$('img[alt="image2"]').hide();
```

To hide the images that have an `alt` containing the word 'image' you can do this (other selector options can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)):

```
$(function() {
    $('img[alt*="image"]').hide();
});
```

Instead of using the `alt` attribute, an other option is to assign a class to the images, so you can select the images depending on their class:

```
$(function() {
    $('.myImageClassName').hide();
});

<img class="myImageClassName" />
```

or to wrap them in a `div` with a unique `id`:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myImageContainer img').hide();
});

<div id="myImageContainer">
    <img />
    <img />
    <img />
</div>
```

Comment: yes I know way with option hide but I need to know way with changing attribute. Do you know where I made mistace?

Comment: Did you include the jQuery library? See first section of my answer.

Comment: yes now my code is working correct but this what I would like to fix in website which I developing all teh time I can see.

Comment: best way to have the images hidden at startup is to assign the same class attribute to all images and to add `display: none` in your css file. Later, to do animations, you select the images depending on that classname.

Answer (score 1):

Just try having an id for each img tag and try using this jquery hide() function...

```
$('#your_img_id').hide();
```

might work...

Comment: I would like to use way with changing attribute